# How to multiply two compressed matrices?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, compression

The goal is to multiply two square (n x n) matrices of any size. However, the matrices are compressed to upper triangular form, and the zeros in the matrix are ignored in order to save space.

Upper triangular form mean that all the entries below the main diagonal are zero.

For example, a 3 dimensional matrix may look like this:

[image: matrix A and B]

Which is can be interpreted as the multiplication between these vectors.

[image: multiplication of matrix a and b]

I've begun my implementation - but it become really messy, and I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this in a way the agrees with the format of my data?

```
The data:
matrixA = 2d vector that contains the row elements of matrixA
matrixB = 2d vector that contains the col elements of matrixB

The goal:
return matrixC = matrixA * matrixB


vector <int> multiplyVectors(vector <vector<int>>* matrixA, vector <vector<int>>* matrixB)
{
    vector<int> results;
    long int summation = 0;
    int matrixA_size = (*matrixA).size();
    int square = matrixB_size;

    int currentRow = 0; 
    int currentRowInner = 0;
    int currentColumn = 0; 
    int currentColumnInner = 0;

    int doItAmount = 1;
    // multiply each column for every row
    while (currentRow <= matrixB_size)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrixA_size; i++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrixA_size; i++)
            {

            ...


}}}}
```

Comment: Goal is to multiply matrices, but you want to multiply vectors? It's a bit confusing using different terms interchangeably.

Comment: 1. "However, the matrices are compressed in rref(), and the zeros in the matrix are ignored in order to save space." What is `rref()`? 2. Are three dimensional matrices relevant to the specifics of the question? If not then that sentence is confusing, as three dimensional matrix multiplication does not have a standard definition and this will throw people off. 3. The signature of your function is that it takes two 2-dimensional matrices, and returns a vector... that is not what either standard matrix multiplication, or standard vector multiplication, does. Can you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: I've added some clarifications.

Comment: Your goal is to return a matrix, but your function example returns a vector. What do you want?

Comment: The returned vector is the resultant matrix read from left to right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product of two upper triangular matrices is also an upper triangular matrix. So you only need to compute those terms. The sum of products for each result term has only one product on the center diagonal (which is just the product of the multiplicand diagonals), two products for the next diagonal up, and so on to *n* products for the single upper right term, where you are multiplying *n* x *n* matrices.

So it is a simple matter of writing the outer loop and inner loop to compute the proper number of terms and sum them for each term in the result, so as to not waste time multiplying and adding zeros.  This will significantly reduce the number of additions and multiplications from *n<sup>2</sup>* and *n<sup>3</sup>* for a normal matrix multiplication to *n(n-1)/2* and *n(n+1)(n+2)/6* for a product of upper diagonal matrices.  For large *n*, this reduces the amount of work by a factor of six.